# Connecting a Windows Phone 8 Emulator to Host machine

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, hyper-v

I've recently upgraded from VS2010 to VS2012 and the emulator is now a virtual machine, which means that my previous calls to the service running locally which were accomplished using /localhost/service/ now no longer work.  I need to use the IP address of the actual machine in order for the calls to see it.

That creates two problems:
1) I often have to work offline, so I'm not sure there is an IP address to use at all
2) Doesn't that make sharing code difficult, as each person will have to constantly update the code in order to run it locally?

It seems more likely like I'm missing something very easy, because I haven't seen anything that addresses these concerns, and I would imagine that this is a *very* common usage.  Most apps need to reach external services, and more than likely, if you're running in debug, you want to run them locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem by including the following T4 template into your windows phone project:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Management" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Management" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
using System.Net;

public static class SelfIpAddress
{
    public static readonly IPAddress dbgHostAddress = new IPAddress( new byte[ 4 ] { <#= String.Join( ", ", address ) #> } );
}<#+
    static IEnumerable<ManagementObject> searchWmi( string q )
    {
        var mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher( q );
        return mos.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>();
    }

    static byte[] findTheAddress()
    {
        string q1 = @"SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter where ServiceName='VMSMP' and NetConnectionID is not NULL";

        ManagementObject adapter = searchWmi( q1 ).Where( mo => mo[ "NetConnectionID" ].ToString().Contains( "Emulator Internal Switch" ) ).FirstOrDefault();
        if( null == adapter )
            throw new Exception( "Network adapter was not found" );

        int interfaceIndex = int.Parse( adapter[ "InterfaceIndex" ].ToString() );

        string q2 = @"SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where InterfaceIndex = " + interfaceIndex.ToString();
        ManagementObject adapterConfig = searchWmi( q2 ).FirstOrDefault();
        string address = ( adapterConfig[ "IPAddress" ] as string[] ).FirstOrDefault();
        if( null == address )
            throw new Exception( "Network adapter has no address" );
        return address.Split( '.' ).Select( c => byte.Parse( c ) ).ToArray();
    }

    readonly byte[] address = findTheAddress();
#>
```

On my machine it produces the following source file:

```
using System.Net;

public static class SelfIpAddress
{
    public static readonly IPAddress dbgHostAddress = new IPAddress( new byte[ 4 ] { 169, 254, 80, 80 } );
}
```

Then in your code you can use `SelfIpAddress.dbgHostAddress` value to access your host. Just like everyone else who works on the project. To refresh the value, press BUILD, then "Transform All T4 Templates".

Comment: thanks for your help, but it looks like the class you used isn't available on the phone version of .net [ManagementObject Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Actually, the entire `System.Management` namespace seems to not be on the phone.

Comment: It doesn’t matter. T4 templates run on your PC inside your visual studio.

Comment: That's why inside them you can use any API available on your PC, even if that T4 file is included in a windows phone project.

Comment: You're right!  Thank you! Sorry it too me so long to try it out.  it does work, on my machine that IP address is the same as yours, I wonder if it's just a special loopback on windows.

Thanks again!